# How to get an aggregation separated by type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index "my_index" and 2 types "color1" and "color2". Each doc in both types has a field "color".

Doing aggregation over "color" and whole index i will get something like this:

```
[{ "key": "red", "doc_count": 10},  
{ "key": "blue", "doc_count": 9},  
{ "key": "green", "doc_count": 8}]
```

Is it possible without 2 queries to get something like:

```
[{ "key": "color1.red", "doc_count": 7},  
{ "key": "color1.blue", "doc_count": 6},  
{ "key": "color1.green", "doc_count": 5},
{ "key": "color2.red", "doc_count": 3},  
{ "key": "color2.blue", "doc_count": 3},  
{ "key": "color2.green", "doc_count": 3}]
```

or:

```
{"color1":    
[{ "key": "red", "doc_count": 7},  
{ "key": "blue", "doc_count": 6},  
{ "key": "green", "doc_count": 5}],
"color2":    
[{ "key": "red", "doc_count": 3},  
{ "key": "blue", "doc_count": 3},  
{ "key": "green", "doc_count": 3}]}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_color": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```